# Colors are not showing up on the OpenGL window

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2, game-development, glew

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MainGame.h"

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    MainGame maingame;
    maingame.run();

       return 0;
}
```

MainGame.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
enum class GameState
{
    PLAY,EXIT
};


class MainGame
{
    public:
        MainGame();
        ~MainGame();

        void run();



    private:
        void initsystem();
        void gameLoop();

        void processInput();
        void drawGame();


        SDL_Window* _window;
        int _screenWidth;
        int _screenHeight;

        GameState _gameState;
};
```

MainGame.cpp

```
#include "MainGame.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


void fatalError(std::string errorString)
{
    std::cout<<errorString<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Enter any key"<<std::endl;
    int tmp;
    std::cin>>tmp;
    SDL_Quit();
}

MainGame::MainGame()
{
    _window=nullptr;

    _screenWidth=640;
    _screenHeight=480;
    _gameState=GameState::PLAY;
}

MainGame::~MainGame()
{

}

void MainGame::run()
{
    initsystem();
    gameLoop();
}

void MainGame::initsystem()
{
    //initialize SDL
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    _window=SDL_CreateWindow("Game",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,_screenWidth,_screenHeight,SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if(_window==nullptr)
    {
        fatalError("Sdl window failed to load");
    }


    SDL_GLContext glContex=SDL_GL_CreateContext(_window);
    if(glContex==nullptr)
    {
        fatalError("SDL_Glcontex failed to load");
    }

    GLenum error =glewInit();
    if(error !=GLEW_OK)
    {
        fatalError("could no initialize Glew!");
    }
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER,1);
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f);

}
void MainGame::gameLoop()
{
    while(_gameState!=GameState::EXIT)
    {
        processInput();
    }

}

void MainGame::processInput()
{
    SDL_Event evnt;

    while(SDL_PollEvent(&evnt))
    {
        switch(evnt.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            _gameState=GameState::EXIT;
            break;

        case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            std::cout<<evnt.motion.x<<" "<<evnt.motion.y<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void MainGame::drawGame()
{
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex2f(0,0);
    glVertex2f(0,500);
    glVertex2f(500,0);
    glEnd();


    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(_window);


}
```

so i was following an OpenGL tutorial and everything was alright until colors got involved and the one i am following is using a window PC and i am using Debian and the code compiles just fine but i am not getting anything in the output.[![  that's the output !!

i mean i should a blue screen and a triangle.

and i am using there linker in code::block -lSDL2 -lglut -lGLEW -lGLU -lm -lGL 
i don't know if i am missing some imp linker or something is wrong with the code itself.

[image]

Comment: You never call `drawGame`, at least not in the shown code. You probably want to call it in `gameLoop`.

Comment: @churill ohh!! anyway thanks dude